# How to use a specific latex template in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I would like to create this Latex template in org-mode :

```
\documentclass[french, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{antiqua}
\author{My Name}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières}
```

So I have added this to my .emacs in order to not have any of the default packages, just the one I want, based on what I saw on this [tutorial](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html#org9b31f0b) :

```
(require 'ox-latex)
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
           '("koma-article"
             "\documentclass[french, 11pt]{scrartcl}
             \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
             \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
             \usepackage{babel}
             \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
             \usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
             \usepackage{microtype}
             \usepackage{antiqua}
             \author{My Name}
             \date{\today}
             \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières}
             [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
             [NO-PACKAGES]"
             ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
             ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
             ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
             ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
             ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))))
```

So that when I want to create a new document in org-mode I just have to put :

```
#+TITLE: My Title
#+LaTeX_CLASS: koma-article
```

However when I try to compile a document I get :`Unknown LaTeX class 'koma-article'`. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Is there a way to load only these packages without having to specify then in the buffer using `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage` ?

Comment: Are you sure about the code? All backslashes should be escaped, e.g. `\\documentclass`, `\\usepackage`. Otherwise you're going to end up with an error in your `add-to-list` call.

Comment: Check the value of `org-latex-classes` with `C-h v org-latex-classes RET`. As @Zeta points out, you are probably not adding the entry.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks, you're right escaping all the backslashes worked. Sorry, I guess that what happens when you edit your config at 5 a.m ^^'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the latex commands need to be escaped. so this should work as expected....

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
           '("koma-article"
             "\\documentclass[french, 11pt]{scrartcl}
             \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
             \\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
             \\usepackage{babel}
             \\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
             \\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
             \\usepackage{microtype}
             \\usepackage{antiqua}
             \\author{My Name}
             \\date{\\today}
             \\renewcommand{\\contentsname}{Table des matières}
             [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
             [NO-PACKAGES]"
             ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
             ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
             ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
             ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
             ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Answer (score 1):

According with what you are describing, I would recommend you to escape all the backslashes (all the backslashes that appear between the "koma-article" and  [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]).
Finally, you need to make sure that you have the Koma-Script ‘article’ class installed: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to have an own latex header file, and input it at the very beginning of your file.

```
   ("mybestreport"
           "\\input{/home/path/to/your/latex/header/header.tex}"
           ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
           ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
           ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
           ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
           ("\\fourthsection{%s}" . "\\fourthsection*{%s}")
           ("\\fifthsection{%s}" . "\\fifthsection*{%s}")
           )
```